# Have siblings communicate via events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, event-handling, dom-events

I need one sibling to respond when another sibling fires an event. Here is the parent component, which contains both siblings:

```
class ChatWindow extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='ChatWindow'>
                <MessageList />
                <ChatBar onResize={this.handleChatBarResize.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleChatBarResize() {
        console.log('Chat bar resized');
        // Now I need to let MessageList know that the chat bar was resized
    }

}
```

When the Chat bar is resized, the `handleChatBar()` function is called after being bubbled up to `ChatWindow`. I then need to trigger an event in `MessageList` when `handleChatBar()` is called, preferably without using any globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

1. Use state in conatiner conponent:  `state = { isChatBarResized : false }`
2. On `handleChatBarResized()` change state `this.setState({ isChatBarResized : true })`
3. On render, pass to `MessageList` the flag from state: `<MessageList  isChatBarResized={this.state.isChatBarResized} />`
4. In `MessageList.componentWillReciveProps()` check if flag was changed, then do your stuff.

Don't forget to set back `this.state.isChatBarResized` after you finish your stuff. You can raise up an event that father container will catch and change there this flag.

Comment: I decided to go with your solution and its working well (although I'm using Redux so it was a bit more work to implement). Before seeing your answer, I had actually solved it by passing an array of functions to `MessageList` via props, and then in `MessageList`'s `componentDidMount` function, I pushed the needed function into the array of functions. That way, in the `ChatWindow`, I could simply iterate through the array and call each function in the array, which worked fine. However, I think your solution is better as it does a better job at adhering to React's design principles.

Comment: For redux case, you can do it simply by dispatching actions instead of using props callbacks and use store global state instead of using parent-children props passing. I think that the better approach is without reudx use for this case, because other components don't need this shared data.